# Remove certain elements from an RSS feed such as short codes

Tags: wordpress

I am using some short code functions which generates content in my posts, when the post is generated through an rss feed the short codes don't format correctly

Just wondering if their is anyway to remove certain elements from an rss feed such as short codes?

Thanks

Comment: are you adding short code to content?

Comment: I just need to remove that short code in RSS feed @raunak Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your theme `functions.php` file.

**Hide all the Shortcode in content from RSS feed:**

```
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'theme_slug_custom_feed');
add_filter('the_content', 'theme_slug_custom_feed');

function theme_slug_custom_feed( $content )
{
    global $post;

    if ( ! is_feed() )
        return $content;

    // Remove all shortcodes
    $content = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );

return $content;
}
```

Comment: I need to hide short code in Feed, Not in website..Is it okay @Raunak Gupta ?

Comment: Yes the above code will remove the short code form RSS feed only, I have checked `if ( ! is_feed() )` so it will not do any thing in post/page of the web site. What the issue you are facing now, after writing the above code.

Comment: Let me check with using above code.. Thank you. @raunak Gupta

Comment: @narola: have you checked my answer?